# Atomic update of a SOLR document. Updating fields on document instead of full reindex of document

Tags: solr, content-search

SOLR has a feature for doing partial updates of a document called [Atomic Updates](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html#UpdatingPartsofDocuments-AtomicUpdates). The SOLR documentation has this example:

```
{
   "id":"mydoc",
   "price":{"set":99},
   "popularity":{"inc":20},
   "categories":{"add":["toys","games"]},
   "promo_ids":{"remove":"a123x"},
   "tags":{"remove":["free_to_try","on_sale"]}
}
```

Where the keywords `set`, `inc`, `add`, `remove` performs different kinds of updates.

Can this be done through the Sitecore Search api?

I can see that SOLRNet has a class called [AtomicUpdateCommand](https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet/blob/master/SolrNet/Commands/AtomicUpdateCommand.cs).If Sitecore does not support Atomic Updates, what is the best way to access the underlying SOLRNet object?

The objective of my work is to be able to run through an index and update all items with Page View statistics from third party analytics data.

Comment: There is an example on the documentation site on calling solrnet in sitecore. I hope this can help you. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/using-solr-to-group-search-results.html